# How to print a section of a HTML page with formatting

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I'm trying to print the table off on my page without printing off the entire webpage.

```
                  <table class="table" id="printTable">
                    <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Example 1</th>
                      <th>Example 2</th>
                    </tr>
                    <loopstart:namedetails:>
                    <tr>
                      <td>$Name</td>
                      <td>$Example1</td>
                      <td>$Example2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <loopend>
                  </table>
```

I've tried to use javascript to print it off like

```
var prtContent = document.getElementById("printTable");
var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
WinPrint.document.close();
WinPrint.focus();
WinPrint.print();
```

But the page loses all its styling and looks rubbish!

Comment: Rather than opening a new window, you could apply some [print-specific CSS](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-printer-friendly-pages/) (including hiding the bits you don't want to print out, of course) to the existing page to modify its appearance as per your printing requirements, and then print that. None of this has anything to do with PHP, btw - I edited your post accordingly.

Comment: You could try working tooooo hard